# g-wan kv store KV_INCR_KEY

Tags: key-value-store, g-wan

How to use the `KV_INCR_KEY`?
I found a useful feature in gwan api, but without any sample.
I want to add items to the KV store with this as primary key.
Also, how to get the value of this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KV_INCR_KEY` value is a flag intended to be passed to `k_add()`.

You get the newly inserted key's value by checking the return value of `k_add()`. The [documentation](http://gwan.ch/api#kv) states:

```
kv_add(): add/update a value associated to a key
return: 0:out of memory, else:pointer on existing/inserted kv_item struct
```

This was derived from an idea discussed on the G-WAN forum. And, like for some other flags (timestamp or persistence, for example), it has not not been implemented yet (`KV_NO_UPDATE` is functional).

Since what follows the next version (focussed on new scripted languages) is a kind of zero-configuration `mapReduce`, the KV store will get more attention soon.